# How to truncate or delete partition from db2 using bigsql?

Tags: hive, biginsights, bigsql

I have table in db2 (using bigsql) that is partitioned as per date on IBM BigInsights

```
table_name_abc
   20150810
      data corresponding to partition
   20150811
      data corresponding to partition
   ....
```

what I want is to delete particular partition say `20150810` or delete data from that partition

I tried this

```
db2 "truncate table test_schema.table_name_abc where partition_date = 20150810";
```

But it gave following error

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "where" was found following "test_table".
Expected tokens may include:  "".  SQLSTATE=42601
```

Can someone please instruct on how to do this?

Comment: `TRUNCATE` deletes all data in the table and `WHERE` is not supported by DB2. You could do `DELETE FROM test_schema.table_name_abc WHERE partition_date = 20150810`

Comment: @data_henrik I tried that also but it errors out 

`db2 "delete from test_schema.table_name_abc where partition_date = 20150515";`

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0150N  The target fullselect, view, typed table, materialized query table,
range-clustered table, or staging table in the INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, MERGE,
or TRUNCATE statement is a target for which the requested operation is not
permitted.  SQLSTATE=42807

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by using the following command

`db2 "ALTER TABLE test_schema.table_name_abc DROP PARTITION (partition_date = 20150515)";`

Adding it as answer just in case someone needs it